# How to send sms to mobile station through hex values?

Tags: sms, messaging, at-command, mms

I need to send sms using hex values.

I have some SMS pdu which i convert it to heximal.
Now i need to send this heximal value to check the message.

Anybody any idea how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a solution :

Please refer to the link below :

[How to send SMS by GSM modem in PDU mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489717/how-to-send-sms-by-gsm-modem-in-pdu-mode)

Thanks.