# Is there a way to send a silent sms with gsm modem?

Tags: sms, gsm, at-command, modem, silent

Is it possible to send "Silent SMS" (also called Stealth SMS / Ping SMS) with using gsm modem?

Modem supports a set of Hayes commands (or "[at commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set)").

I tried to find the AT-command that send this type of SMS messages, but, unfortunately, I found only getting regular SMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Instead of sending a plain text SMS, you are going to have to send in PDU mode (assuming your modem supports PDU mode. Most do.) and build the PDU yourself with a message type 0.

Here is a link to PDU format: [GSM 03.40](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.40)

Here's a link to a previous discussion about PDU mode on modems: [How to send SMS by GSM modem in PDU mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489717/how-to-send-sms-by-gsm-modem-in-pdu-mode)